# Is there anyway to not repeat code here?

Tags: python

```
import random
import time
import sys
inventory = []
print "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
print "        Welcome         "
print "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
print "You find youself waking up in a cold dark room."
print ""
print "You look around and find 3 door ways in front of you: One to the left, one to the right and one in the middle and a chest." 
print ""
print "You have to make a choice. Type the direction of the room to enter the room or type 'Search' to search the chest."
print ""
choice = raw_input("Please make your selection:")



if choice == ("Search") or  ("search"):
    print "You slowly walk towards the chest and reach in and find:"
    x = random.randint(1,2)
    if x == 1:
        print "You find a sword!"
        inventory.append("Sword")
    if x == 2:
        print "You find an axe!"
        inventory.append("Axe")
    print "You search some more..."
    time.sleep(3)
    y = random.randint(1,2)
    if y == 1:
        print "You also found a torch."
        inventory.append("Torch")
    if y == 2:
        print "You also found a shield."
        inventory.append("Shield")
    choice = raw_input("Please pick a direction you'd like to go:")



if choice == ("Left") or ("left"):
    time.sleep(2)
    print "You enter the room to the left"
    string = "Torch"
    if string in inventory:
        print "You take your  torch and look around."
        time.sleep(2)
        print"You notice a glimmer in the corner of the room."
        time.sleep(2)
        print"As you step closer you find that the glimmer starts to grow."
        time.sleep(2)
        print "As you come feet away, your torch reveales a giant spider!"
        string = "Torch"
        if string in inventory:
            time.sleep(1)
            print "You take out your torch!"
            print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
            print ("                  Fighting...                   ")
            print ("   YOU MUST HIT ABOVE A 5 TO KILL THE SPIDER    ")
            print ("IF THE SPIDER HITS HIGHER THAN YOU, YOU WILL DIE")
            print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
            time.sleep(2)
            PDmg = int(random.randint(3, 10))
            EDmg = int(random.randint(1, 5))
            print ("You hit a", PDmg)
            print ("The spider hits a", EDmg)
            time.sleep(2)
            #This part calculates who won
            if EDmg > PDmg:
                print ("The spider has done more damage and killed you!")
                print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
                print ("                  GAME IS OVER!                 ")
                print ("                  QUITTING PROGRAM              ")
                print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
                time.sleep(5)
                sys.exit()
            elif PDmg < 5:
                print ("You managed to hit injure the spider, but not kill it.")
                print ("Luckily, you escaped to the main room")
                choice = raw_input("Please select a room to enter:")
            elif PDmg > 5:
                print "You killed the spider, congratulations!"
                print "You have been rewarded with armour!"
                print "You return to the main room!"
                spider = 1
                inventory.append("Armour")
                choice = raw_input("Please select a room to enter:")



    else:
        print "You cannot see a thing! You squint to try and find any resources"
        time.sleep(2)
        print "You see a glimmer come closer and closer, what could it be!"
        time.sleep(2)
        print "It appears to be a giant spider!"
        string = "Shield"
        if string in inventory:
            time.sleep(1)
            print "You take out your trusty shield!"
            time.sleep(2)
            print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
            print ("                  Fighting...                   ")
            print ("   YOU MUST HIT ABOVE A 5 TO KILL THE SPIDER    ")
            print ("IF THE SPIDER HITS HIGHER THAN YOU, YOU WILL DIE")
            print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
            time.sleep(2)
            PDmg = int(random.randint(3, 10))
            EDmg = int(random.randint(1, 4))
            print ("You hit a", PDmg)
            print ("The spider hits a", EDmg)
            time.sleep(2)
            #This part calculates who won
            if EDmg > PDmg:
                print ("The spider has done more damage and killed you!")
                print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
                print ("                  GAME IS OVER!                 ")
                print ("                  QUITTING PROGRAM              ")
                print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
                time.sleep(5)
                sys.exit()
            elif PDmg < 5:
                print ("You managed to hit injure the spider, but not kill it.")
                print ("Luckily, you escaped to the main room")
                choice = raw_input("Please select a room to enter:")
            elif PDmg > 5:
                print "You killed the spider, congratulations!"
                print "You have been rewarded with armour!"
                print "You return to the main room!"
                spider = 1
                inventory.append("Armour")
                choice = raw_input("Please select a room to enter:")
        else:
            print "You don't have anything in your inventory!"
            print "You attempt to fight the spider..."
            print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
            print ("                  Fighting...                   ")
            print ("   YOU MUST HIT ABOVE A 5 TO KILL THE SPIDER    ")
            print ("IF THE SPIDER HITS HIGHER THAN YOU, YOU WILL DIE")
            print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
            time.sleep(2)
            PDmg = int(random.randint(1, 2))
            EDmg = int(random.randint(1, 50))
            print ("You hit a", PDmg)
            print ("The spider hits a", EDmg)
            if EDmg > PDmg:
                print ("The spider has done more damage and killed you!")
                print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
                print ("                  GAME IS OVER!                 ")
                print ("                  QUITTING PROGRAM              ")
                print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
                time.sleep(5)
                sys.exit()
            if PDmg > EDmg:
                print "Somehow, you managed to tap the spider and run away alive!"
                choice = raw_input("Please select a room to enter:")

if choice == ("Right") or ("right"):
    time.sleep(1)
    print "You walk into the Right room."
    time.sleep(1)
    print "You find 3 bridges, and a sign:"
    print "You may either leave empty handed, or pick the right path for a bounty."
    Bchoice = input("Please select which bridge to cross: 1 , 2 , or , 3:")
    if Bchoice == 2:
        string = "Armour"
        if string in inventory:
            print "Crossing..."
            time.sleep(2)
            print "The bridge has not crumbled, you see a glimmering chest."
            print "You find an extra sharp blade, it seems to be for cutting stone."
            inventory.append("SharpBlade")
            choice = raw_input("Please select a room:")
        else:
            print "Crossing..."
            time.sleep(2)
            print "The bridge has crumbled, you have fallen to your death."
            print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
            print ("                  GAME IS OVER!                 ")
            print ("                  QUITTING PROGRAM              ")
            print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
            time.sleep(5)
            sys.exit()
    else:
        print "Crossing..."
        time.sleep(2)
        print "The bridge has crumbled, you have fallen to your death."
        print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        print ("                  GAME IS OVER!                 ")
        print ("                  QUITTING PROGRAM              ")
        print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        time.sleep(5)
        sys.exit()
if choice == ("Straight") or ("straight"):
    print "You enter the middle room."
    time.sleep(1)
    print "You find a gargoyle towering 50 feet above you!"
    print "You have 3 options, climb, fight or flee."
    Fchoice = raw_input("Please decide to Climb, Fight or Flee.")
    while Fchoice != "Flee":
        while Fchoice == ("Climb") , ("climb"):
            print "You have climbed the gargoyle and prepare to cut off the head."
            string = "SharpBlade"
            if string in inventory:
                time.sleep(2)
                print "Your extra sharp blade cuts off the head and the gargoyle falls!"
                print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
                print ("                  YOU WON!!!!!!!!!               ")
                print ("                  QUITTING PROGRAM              ")
                print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
                time.sleep(5)
                sys.exit("You have beat the puzzle RPG text based adventure game!")
            else:
                print "You fail to cut off the head."
                print "The gargoyle throws you off and kills you."
                print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
                print ("                  GAME IS OVER!                 ")
                print ("                  QUITTING PROGRAM              ")
                print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
                time.sleep(5)
                sys.exit()
        if Fchoice == "Fight":
            print "You un-shealth your sword, only to find the gargoyles hand ontop of your body."
            print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
            print ("                  GAME IS OVER!                 ")
            print ("                  QUITTING PROGRAM              ")
            print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
            time.sleep(5)
            sys.exit()
    print "You try to flee, but the Gargoyle stops you by kicking you against the wall!"
    print "You un-shealth your sword, only to find the gargoyles hand ontop of your body."
    print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    print ("                  GAME IS OVER!                 ")
    print ("                  QUITTING PROGRAM              ")
    print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    time.sleep(5)
    sys.exit()
```

I am creating a RPG based text game with a little bit of combat. There is a specific order to getting things and going into rooms.

Basically, I know repeating code is bad, but I'm not sure the steps I would have to take to do so. I'm pretty sure I need to use functions and def main(). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: put it in a function and just call the function

Comment: There's quite a few tutorials about writing text adventures out on the web: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+text+adventure You might find reading through some of them helpful; more general advice could lead you to good ideas for your own code.

Comment: you need to learn about loops and functions. ...

Answer (score 0):

You want to separate your logic more than you have already. When you do so, it becomes far more clear when it is not a good idea to repeat something.

So lets start at the very beginning.

Your game easily falls under the MVC architecture. In MVC architecture you divide your logic into models, views and controllers.

Your inventory is a model, every time you print to the screen you should be calling a view, and all of the logic of controlling your game would be your controller.

A good layout for such would be to start with a `Game` class. This class will be your controller. Next, create an `Interface` class. Create methods in your `Interface` which will be called every time you print to the screen or prompt the user. In your game class, you can have the logic of running through the app, prompting the user, calling the view when you want to print to the screen, and calling the inventory to update it as necessary.

Here are some resources to look at:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm
http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html

This looks like a tutorial for something similar to what you are trying to do:
http://letstalkdata.com/2014/08/how-to-write-a-text-adventure-in-python/

Welcome to programming! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to type the entire thing out but I think you would be a lot better of handling "character" with objects and keeping track of hp, inventory etc. Take a look at the spider fight and how the object does all the work for you. Most of the scene setting can be looped but for sake of me not feeling like writing it all out I will leave it as is.

```
import random, time, sys
welcome_message = '''
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\tWelcome         
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
You find youself waking up in a cold dark room.

You look around and find 3 door ways in front of you: One to the left, one to the right and one in the middle and a chest.

You have to make a choice. Type the direction of the room to enter the room or type 'Search' to search the chest.

'''

class Character(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = 100
        self.is_dead = False

    def take_damage(self, damage):
        self.damage = damage
        print '{0} has taken {1} damage!'.format(self, self.damage)
        self.hp = self.hp - self.damage
        if self.hp <= 0:
            self.is_dead = True

    def is_alive(self):
        if self.is_dead:
            print '{0} has died!'.format(self)
            return False
        return True

    def damage_taken(self):
        return self.damage

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

class Spider(Character):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Spider, self).__init__(name)

class Adventurer(Character):

    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Adventurer, self).__init__(name)
        self.inventory = []

    def has_inventory(self, item):
        if item.lower() in self.inventory:
            return True
        return False

    def is_alive(self):
        if self.is_dead:
            print 'You have died.'
            sys.exit()
        return True

    def show_inventory(self):
        return self.inventory

    def add_inventory(self, item):
        if item.lower() not in self.inventory:
            self.inventory.append(item.lower())

adventurer = Adventurer('Tom')

print welcome_message
user_choice = raw_input('Please make your selection:').lower()

if user_choice == 'search':
    print 'You slowly walk towards the chest and reach in and find:'
    weapon = random.choice(['Axe', 'Sword'])
    print 'You find a {0}'.format(weapon)
    adventurer.add_to_inventory(weapon)
    ...
    ...
    user_choice = raw_input('Please pick a direction you\'d like to go:').lower()

if user_choice == 'left':   

    if adventurer.has_inventory('Torch'):
        ...
        ...

        spider = Spider('Spider')

        while spider.is_alive() and adventurer.is_alive():
            spider.take_damage(random.randint(3, 10))
            adventurer.take_damage(random.randint(1, 5))
```